# Scrolling problem in nested UIScrollViews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have 2 scrollviews, super scrollview includes multiple scrollviews inside. Super scrollview will make paging and horizontal scrolling, while each small scrollview makes vertical scrolling without paging.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to solve that problem is to avoid it.

But you may be able to get acceptable behavior from it by manipulating the `UIGestureRecognizer`s that each has.  There are three on each scroll view.  You could tell some of them that that have to wait for others to fail before they succeed.  This could mollify the angry interactions between them.

Good luck.